# Incorporate an existing C# file to a C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm learning visual studio. I have a very simple console application project in C# and I want to add an existing file with C# classes defined on it to this existing project. I want the project to recognize this file. How can I do this?

This is my project, it is currently empty:

[image]

This is the file I want to add:

[image]

My goal is to see the Addressbook.cs from my class Program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on "ConsoleApplication1" project and click "Add > Existing Item..." and select the file.

Comment: @DiegoOrellana, be sure "accept" sammy's answer by clicking on the checkmark by the answer. :)